# SQL DDL: Recursive table with two foreign keys (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, ddl, recursive-query

I have a `subject` table that is recursive because a subject can be a prerequisite of another subject:

- A subject can have no prerequisites
- A subject can have 1 prerequisite
- A subject can have 2 prerequisites

Since there are subjects with 2 prerequisites, I made the `prerequisite_1` and the `prerequisite_2` columns FKs pointing to the `subject_code` column:

```
CREATE TABLE subject(
    subject_code CHAR(7),
    subject_desc VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    no_of_units TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL CHECK(no_of_units >= 0 AND no_of_units < 13),
    prerequisite_1 CHAR(7),
    prerequisite_2 CHAR(7),
    PRIMARY KEY(subject_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(prerequisite_1, prerequisite_2) REFERENCES subject(subject_code)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

I tried the code on SQL Fiddle and the table is not being created.

How do I create a recursive table with 1 PK column and 2 FK columns pointing back to the table's own PK?

Comment: I believe your syntax is wrong, try changing the `foreign key` stuff for each foreign key into: `CONSTRAINT \`subject_ibfk_1\` FOREIGN KEY (\`prerequisite_1\`) REFERENCES \`subject\` (\`subject_code\`)` (`ON DELETE CASCADE`?) Substituting all `_1` with `_2` off course.

Comment: Instead of arbitrarily limiting yourself to 2 prerequisites, you could use a separate reference table that relates subjects to their prerequisites.

Comment: @Barmar So far, subjects have 2 prerequisites at most, but if I were apply your suggestion, how must it be done (SQL code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split them into two separate foreign keys, and you should probably (but don't have to) name them;

```
CREATE TABLE subject(
    subject_code CHAR(7),
    subject_desc VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    no_of_units TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL 
       CHECK(no_of_units >= 0 AND no_of_units < 13),
    prerequisite_1 CHAR(7),
    prerequisite_2 CHAR(7),
    PRIMARY KEY(subject_code),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_pr1(prerequisite_1) REFERENCES subject(subject_code),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_pr2(prerequisite_2) REFERENCES subject(subject_code)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

[An SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb10f).

Comment: Thank you, this worked (I removed the fk_pr1 and fk_pr2 though) and I was also able to insert data flawlessly. May I ask why must I (must I not) name foreign keys? What is its significance?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting prerequisites in the `subject` table, use a many-to-many relation table:

```
CREATE TABLE prerequisite (
    subject_code CHAR(7),
    prerequisite CHAR(7),
    PRIMARY KEY (subject_code, prerequisite),
    FOREIGN KEY (subject_code) REFERENCES subject(subject_code),
    FOREIGN KEY (prerequisite) REFERENCES subject(subject_code)
)
```

This allows an arbitrary number of prerequisites.

Comment: +1 This solution is more expendable when the number of prerequisites can be unknown. The downside I guess is an extra table and the number of rows can be very large (O(#subject^2)).

Answer (score 0):

So, here is my comment worked out:

I believe your syntax is wrong, try changing the `foreign key` stuff for each foreign key into:

```
CREATE TABLE subject(
    .........

    CONSTRAINT `subject_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`prerequisite_1`) REFERENCES `subject` (`subject_code`),

    CONSTRAINT `subject_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`prerequisite_2`) REFERENCES `subject` (`subject_code`)

)ENGINE=INNODB;
```